# How to generate an openapi.yaml file from source code within a GitLab pipeline?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, gitlab-ci, openapi

I have created an openapi rest controller in Java Spring Boot. Now I would like to check that openapi specification with a API linter like "Spectral" within a Gitlab-CI. Therefore I need a openapi.yaml or openapi.json file as input for that API-linter command line tool.

So, how to create that openapi file on command line without starting the application?

Currently I have to start the application. After that I can call `wget http://localhost:8080/api-docs` to get the API specification as an openapi.yaml file. But this is not the way in a Gitlab-ci. The check of the API should be automated and therefore a command line tool is needed to parse the source code and create the openapi.yaml/json file.

Comment: What library do you use - Springfox or Springdoc?

Comment: ```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```